# Word-Cloud using d3js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, d3-cloud

I am trying to use d3js source code available on GitHub to plot WordCloud.
[GitHub](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud)

My index.html file is as follows:

```
<html xmlns="html">
    <head>
        <title>Visualization Medley</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="medley.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h3>Word Cloud</h3>
<div id="world-cloud"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"/><\script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/d3.layout.js"/><\script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/medley.js"/> 
<\script>
</body>
</html>
```

My d3.layout.js file contains following code:
[Source Code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/master/build/d3.layout.cloud.js)

My medley.js source code:
[Source Code](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/blob/master/examples/browserify.js)

When I open my index.html file it doesn't show me the default wordcloud. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?
I have no prior experience in writing JavaScript/html codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a slightly modified version of your code which displays the cloud:

```js
var fill = d3.scale.category20();

var layout = d3.layout.cloud()
    .size([500, 500])
    .words([
      "Hello", "world", "normally", "you", "want", "more", "words",
      "than", "this"].map(function(d) {
      return {text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 90, test: "haha"};
    }))
    .padding(5)
    .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
    .font("Impact")
    .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
    .on("end", draw);

layout.start();

function draw(words) {
  d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", layout.size()[0])
      .attr("height", layout.size()[1])
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + layout.size()[0] / 2 + "," + layout.size()[1] / 2 + ")")
    .selectAll("text")
      .data(words)
    .enter().append("text")
      .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
      .style("font-family", "Impact")
      .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="html">
    <head>
        <title>Visualization Medley</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="medley.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h3>Word Cloud</h3>
<div id="world-cloud"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"/></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/master/build/d3.layout.cloud.js"/></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I first modify the dependency to [jasondavies/d3-cloud](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) to be:

```xml
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/master/build/d3.layout.cloud.js"/></script>
```

And what's most likely the cause of the non-display of the graph is the call to the cloud, which should be:

```
var layout = d3.layout.cloud().size([500, 500]).words([...
```

instead of:

```
var layout = cloud().size([500, 500]).words([...
```